# Laravel: How to make a field required only if another specific field exists?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I have a form that asks for several files, and description of these files. Something like

```
<input type="file" name="file1">
Describe your file:
<input type="text" name="desc1">
```

I want the user to describe the contents of the file, instead of only showing something like `Invoices-final-FinalV30.docx` he might say "Invoices for January, 2018", so when I validate the form, I know how to ask if a field follows a regex, or if the field is required and so on, using the validate() method, but I want something custom, something that makes "desc1" required ONLY if there's a "file1", if there's no "file1" I can safely ignore whatever "desc1" carries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try required_with:anotherfield validation

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation

```
$validator = Validator::make(
$request->all(),
    [
    'file1' =>  'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png', //your file validation
    'desc1'  => 'bail|required_with:file1' //add other description validations
    ]
);
```

For array fields, example named `upload[][file]` , `upload[][desc]`

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'upload.*.file' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png',
    'upload.*.desc' => 'bail|required_with:upload.*.file',
]);
```

Comment: I'm not able to make this thing work, I have used several options, but I don't get it, solution looks great tho, thank you very much

Comment: @luisfer Is it working now? did you changed anything to make it work?

Comment: Actually I didn't, I haven't solved the issue, I'm doing some other things now, to let it cooldown, and I'll retake it, maybe next week. Thanks!